# Google play developer account

Tags: android, google-play

I tried to get googl play developer account alot
But google still refuse my card.
Is there any way to get account without using cards.?
Maybe someone help me and send money to him.

Comment: please write to google and they will guide you further.

Comment: this is off-topic

Answer (score -1):

There is a $25 USD one-time registration fee that you can pay with the following credit or debit cards:

```
MasterCard
Visa
American Express
Discover (U.S. only)
Visa Electron (Outside of the U.S. only)

Note: The types of cards accepted may vary by location.
```

May I know which card are you using?

Comment: Visa card ..debit card from Malaysia bank

Comment: this is off-topic